# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'TextEditingController'

Tags: flutter, firebase, loops, controller, texteditingcontroller

```
for(i= 0; i< 6 ; i++)
Pinput(length: 6,controller: model.otpController[i],
focusNode:focusNode,
androidSmsAutofillMethod:AndroidSmsAutofillMethod.smsUserConsentApi,
listenForMultipleSmsOnAndroid: true,
defaultPinTheme: defaultPinTheme,
hapticFeedbackType: HapticFeedbackType.lightImpact,
onCompleted: (pin) {debugPrint('onCompleted: $pin');},
onChanged: (value) {debugPrint('onChanged: $value');},
```

I try to count the number of wrong otp attempts  , so i use for loop and int otpContrller[i]
Please try to resolve this issue

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of full OTP attempts or for each individual numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for full OTP attempts:

```
int attempts = 0;

Pinput(
    onCompleted: (pin) {
      String actualPin = '9999';
      if (pin == actualPin) {
        attempts = 0;
        print('success');
        return;
      } else {
        print('failed');
        setState(() {
          attempts += 1;
        });
      }
      print(pin);
    },
  ),
  Text('No of Attempts $attempts'),
```